# Generic table editor

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, generics

I have about 40 tables and users should edit data in this tables in browser. 
I believe than it's possible to create one page with dropdown, user select table name in this dropdown and get a grid with "Edit" button.

Does anybody know if such possible? Is it ready projects on Codeplex for such task?

Thanks,

[asp.net developer](http://alexandershapovalov.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look into [Dynamic Data](http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata) I have only played around with it a little, and it seems to do something like what you are wanting.